# How to access list outside procedure

Tags: list, tcl, global, proc

I have this below code,I want to use sorted list which is generated after calling procedure `processDistances` to use outside procedure.I have tried using global command by declaring `distances` global inside procedure and to use outside procedure i rewritten `global distances` outside procedure also.But got error `can't read "distances": no such variable`

Code:

```
proc distance {n1 n2 nd1 nd2} {
    set x1 [expr int([$n1 set X_])]
    set y1 [expr int([$n1 set Y_])]
    set x2 [expr int([$n2 set X_])]
    set y2 [expr int([$n2 set Y_])]

    set d [expr hypot($x2-$x1,$y2-$y1)]

    return [list $nd1 $nd2 $x1 $y1 $d]
}
proc processDistances {count threshold {filter ""}} {
    global node_
    global distances
    set distances {}
    for {set i 1} {$i < $count} {incr i} {
        for {set j 1} {$j < $count} {incr j} {
            # Skip self comparisons
            if {$i == $j} continue

            # Apply target filter
            if {$filter ne "" && $j != $filter} continue

            # Get the distance information
            set thisDistance [distance $node_($i) $node_($j) $i $j]

            # Check that the nodes are close enough
            if {[lindex $thisDistance 4] < $threshold} {
                lappend distances $thisDistance
            }
        }
    }

    # Sort the pairs, by distances

    set distances [lsort -real -increasing -index 4 $distances]



    # Print the sorted list
    foreach tuple $distances {
        puts "{$tuple}"

    }
}
$ns at 5.5 [list processDistances $val(nn) 300 11]
```

Actually I want this sorted list at time 5.5 as a argument of another procedure like

```
proc operation {distances} {
```

So time is also important.I have to have sorted list generated at that particular time.Is there any way to store sorted list at particular time into new variable?just to understand what I want like this .

```
$ns at 5.5 [list processDistances $val(nn) 300 11]-->$nbr #(o/p i.e sorted list)
```

Update:
1. I tried using this below code outside `proc processDistances` just to check whether i can store result of calling into variable.but it prints one value 170 though i change 11to 41 or time.. anything

```
set nbr {}
Set nbr [$ns at 5.5 [list processDistances $val(nn) 300 11]]
Puts $nbr
```

2. I also tried this 
   in `processDistances` I added `return $distances` and after `proc operation` I added below proc

`proc final {} {
    set nbr {}
    set nbr [list processDistances 42 300 11]
    puts $nbr
    operation $nbr
    }
    $ns at 5.5 final`

but puts $nbr command gives output `processDistances 42 125 41`
please help me out.

Comment: Using `global` outside a procedure is pointless: the command creates a link into a local scope from the global scope, and outside a procedure you are already in the global scope. Regarding the error: a variable doesn't exist before it is assigned a value. The global and local `distances` variables are created in tandem when `processDistances` assigns `{}` to the local `distances` (and, through the link, the global one). If you use `distances` in the global scope before `processDistances` has been called, you get this message.

Comment: Instead of defining a global variable, why you just don't return the list from your function?

Comment: @mario Santini Yes when i tried code which i have mentioned in update,I have edited proc code and written `return $distances` at the end of proc.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the code says that the `distances` variable is global, which is fine, but until it's actually written — after the simulator callback fires at simulation time 5.5 — to you still can't read from it; in Tcl, the variable doesn't exist unless it has something in it, even if that something is the empty string. You can make the variable readable (i.e., make it always contain *something*) by doing this at any time:

```
if {![info exist ::distances]} {
    set ::distances {}
}
```

You can skip the `info exist` test part if you're setting the variable at the start of the script.

Comment: I'm being not _quite_ accurate; variables can sort of exist without contents, but that's by having traces and resolution rules and so on. However, they still look like they don't exist to `$`, `set`, etc.; the advanced features can be safely ignored most of the time.

Comment: thanks for your help.but it does not helping me :( can't i store result at 5.5 into variable? like this  Set nbr [$ns at 5.5 [list processDistances $val(nn) 300 11]]

Comment: thanks for your help.but it does not helping me :( can't i store result at 5.5 into variable? like this  `Set nbr [$ns at 5.5 [list processDistances $val(nn) 300 11]] ` as we can do `set nbr [list processDistances $val(nn) 300 11]] `